# iPhone: Problem with tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

This code doesnt work as required and doesnt load full data for the first time and works fine from the next time once scrolled.

```
#define ROW_HEIGHT 110

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog( @"Setting table text." );

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Transaction";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    [cell addSubview:[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40.0, 0.0, 280.0, ROW_HEIGHT - 1)]];
}

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

NSLog( @"Table cell text: %@", [[transactionHistory objectAtIndex:row] description] );

UILabel *labelText = [[cell subviews] lastObject];
labelText.text = [[transactionHistory objectAtIndex:row] description];
labelText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
labelText.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
labelText.numberOfLines = 5;    

return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return ROW_HEIGHT;
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: I refered to this link but didnt help http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/15517-best-way-make-multiline-uitableviewcell.html

Comment: You should be adding the UILabel to the contentView not the cell itself, and is your NSLog printing the correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line

```
    [cell addSubview:[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40.0, 0.0, 280.0, ROW_HEIGHT - 1)]];
```

To

```
   [cell.contentView addSubview:[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40.0, 0.0, 280.0, ROW_HEIGHT - 1)]];
```